# The value of $b$, if $\lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{ae^x-b\cos x+ce^{-x}}{x\sin x})=2$

Tags: calculus, limits

Question :

The value of $b$, if 
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\frac{ae^x-b\cos x+ce^{-x}}{x\sin x})=2$$

Solution : $$= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log_e\left[\frac{4^x-3^x}{4^x-1}\right]}{x}(4^x-1)$$

$$= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\left[1-\frac{3^x-1}{4^x-1}\right]}{\left(\frac{3^x-1}{4^x-1}\right)}\times  \frac{3^x-1}{4^x-1}\times  \frac{4^x-1}{x}$$

I am unable to take it further. Please help on this thanks

Comment: $a=c$. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Using Taylor series and taking an asymptotic equivalent of the order $2$ we get

$$\frac{ae^x-bcosx+ce^{-x}}{x\sin x}\sim_0\frac{a+ax+a\frac{x^2}2-b+b\frac{x^2}{2}+c-cx+c\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^2}$$
so we see that the desired limit is $2$ if and only if

$$a-b+c=0\quad;\quad a-c=0\quad;\quad a+b+c=4$$
hence we get $b=2$.

Answer (score 1):

We start with Taylorexpanding the numerator and denominator:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{ae^x-b\cos(x)+ce^{-x}}{x\sin(x)}\right)\\
=&\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{a+ax+\frac{1}{2}ax^2-b(1-\frac{1}{2}x^2)+c-cx+\frac{1}{2}cx^2+O(x^3)}{x^2+O(x^3)}\right)\\
=&\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{a+c-b+(a-c)x+\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)x^2+O(x^3)}{x^2+O(x^3)}\right)=2\\
\end{align}

From this follows $a+c-b=0$ and $a+b+c=4$. We conclude that $b=2$

Comment: No, because it's not necessary to calculate $b$.

Comment: But, if $a\neq c$, does the limit converge to 2?